# Angular Template Driven Form Control - Dirty is not changing to true even if I edited the form data

Tags: angular6

Here I am looping through the app-form and when I check the status of dirty it's still false even after I made some changes in form.

Here is the editor url of Stackblitz Code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7fvuej

Can someone explain me why is that happening.

**Trail:**

**Step1:**

> You can click the Button Click Me and in the console u can see the status as false as the form was not touched

**Step2:**

> Make some changes for input fields and click the button again. The
>   status will not be changed and it will be still false.

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If you add

```
 console.log(this.f);
```

You'll notice that your form is empty. It doesnt have any controls or any value. It's not a validator issue but the way you're building your form.
Making a template driven form dynamicly (on runtime) is not an easy task.
Here is a tutorial i found online : [Tutorial](https://medium.com/@tobiasgassmann/dynamic-template-driven-forms-in-angular-82fcaf42877)

I'm sorry i can't help you more.

Comment: Hope it's going to help you.